# Golang Regex not matching the optional part even when it is present in the string

Tags: go, regex-group

I am trying to parse some output from a command, I want to check if the command had an error in it, so I look for the string `**Apply Error**`. If there is no error present the previously mentioned string is absent. My regex to match that is `(?s)Ran Apply.+?(\*\*Apply Error\*\*)?`. I am doing this in Golang

This regex does not work even when the string `** Apply Error**` is present in the output, if I remove the last `?` in my regex it works as expected. It captures 2 groups with the second being the optional part.

Examples:
Case - 1 when the string `**Apply Error**` is present

```
Ran Apply for dir: `some random path/something/something`

`**Apply Error**`
```

Output: Match `**Apply Error**` and capture it as a group

Case - 2
When `**Apply Error**` is not present

```
Ran Apply for dir: `some random path/something/something`
some random text
```

Output: Match everything as is

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Um3CNc/1
In the demo even though `** Apply Error**` is present it does not match it

How can I match the optional part?

Comment: Please show (simplified) examples of with and without your target. Also, how can your regex capture 2 groups when only one group is present in your regex?

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)Ran Apply\b(?:.+?(\*\*Apply Error\*\*)|.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` Inline modifier to have the dot match a newline
- `Ran Apply\b` Match literally followed by a word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group
- `.+?(\*\*Apply Error\*\*)` Match 1+ chars, as few as possible and capture `**Apply Error**` in group 1

  - `|` Or
  - `.*` Match the rest of the text
- `)` Close non capture group

See a regex demo [with Apply Error present](https://regex101.com/r/Gn30sJ/1) and [without Apply Error present](https://regex101.com/r/yJvCzA/1).

Comment: I don’t understand why the optional operator in my regex failed to do the trick

Comment: @Shubhangb That is because the `.+?` is non greedy and the group that follows is optional. Because there is nothing following the pattern after it, the pattern can settle for matching as least as possible. Now that there is an anchor `$` it must assert the end of the string, and the `.*` as an alternative matches the whole string in case the \*\*Apply Error\*\* part does not match.